# Razor page view does not refresh after change Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have some stupid problem.

I work with Razor pages **.cshtml** and when i add some code to my **index.cshtml** and save it, run, when app runing i change some code in this page, save, update page in browser and nothing not changed.

Example:

```
<div class="conntainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><h1>Test</h1></div>
</div>
```

I have this code, i will run app, and change  for ex:

```
<div class="conntainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><h1>Changed data</h1></div>
</div>
```

After reboting page data are not changing, how i can fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the downloaded and rendered HTML is cached in your browser? Take a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) for ways to clear your browser's cache. Also, by "after rebooting" do you mean that you rebooted your computer?

Comment: @JamieTaylor i allready do lot thinks, i reboot PC, i clean cash but nothing not help

Comment: Are you using any caching in code? For instance [Response Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: @JamieTaylor no, i not use caching

Comment: @JamieTaylor and i not use ISS(http), i use WEB(HTTPS)

Comment: Can you create a minimal repeatable version? For instance, if you create a new project (using `dotnet new razor` or similar), does the same issue persist?

Comment: @JamieTaylor i have 2 project, server side, and cliend, in client it's working in normal way, but in server cshtml not updating

Comment: Are you experiencing this on the server or on your development machine?

Comment: @JamieTaylor we are found issues, thank u for help!

Answer (score 1):

For me, changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to "Development" (from "Production") within launchSettings.json - "Profiles" (as below)

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

Resolved this issue for me. I suspect as my Environment variable is set to Development within the projects solution these needed to match. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So problem was in to:

> /Properties/launchSettings.json

Was changen this value:

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
```

To fix it, value must be:

```
 "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
```